# schwartz space definition problem

Tags: real-analysis

http://www.scribd.com/doc/90975254/Attempt-Explanation-Szhwarz-Space

questions is in link. I tried to upload it on the site but I did not manage to upload images. Sorry.

Comment: Why don't you consider typing it up?

Answer (score 1):

The second question is clearly (?) a misprint: the word "space" is missing.
A semi-norm is something weaker than a norm. As you understood, $p(x)=0$ does not imply that $x=0$, if $p$ is only a semi-norm. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) for a definition.